# Change the language for a whole new document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm creating different Word Templates with VBA and for each one of them I would set a different language for the whole document.

I tried to use

```
ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID = wdXXX
ActiveDocument.Range.LanguageID = wdXXX
```

without success can you help me, please?

Comment: If the answer does not help, look at my article on the Microsoft site: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b?tm=1579788821357. The proofing language is not a document property. It is actually at the character level but often set in styles.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/868106/word-vba-how-to-change-the-language-for-a-whole-ne.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

The language ID is a property of the **Normal** style. In a standard template, all other styles inherit the language setting from Normal style. This line will set the language for all styles (unless the styles have a parent of **No Style** instead of Normal):

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").LanguageID = wdFrenchCanadian
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It works but I want to be sure to change the LanguageID not to all "normal" style but only in one template.

Comment: As I mentioned in my reply, the language of all other styles comes from the Normal style. That's what "inherit" means.

Comment: The Normal style can be different in each template or document. See more at your cross-post at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/868106/word-vba-how-to-change-the-language-for-a-whole-ne.html.